# Can't resolve absolute path in mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I did some test using mocha and testem and found some wierd behavior of the path resolver.

The function

```
 function (postfix) {
     var result = process.cwd()+postfix;
     return result;
     };
```

that did return the absolute path with postfix didn't returned it but only postfix. And in normal environment it works as expected.

I created a supplementary repo
https://github.com/chilicoder/bug-with-path
 to show the bug. It raises in 0.10, 0.12 and 4.1 node versions.

Does anybody can explain where is the problem? Because now I can't resolve absolute path to file.

UPDATE: I made an issue in mocha repo https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1940
Waiting for the answer

Comment: I tried to start the test without testem. Same issue.

Comment: Everything works fine for me. I created folder /home/chilicoder/repos. Then I cloned repo there. `npm start` shows me /home/chilicoder/repos/bug-with-path/test/somepath/somefile and `npm test` shows "2 passing".

Comment: thats wierd.
I tried on two computers and tests were not passing. Will try more.

thanks for your comment!

Comment: I suggest you to use cwd() in your test instead of setting your local path. Like this `assert.equal(absPath, process.cwd() + '/test/somepath/somefile');`

Comment: but that exactly what I'm trying to do. But cwd() in tests behaves inconsistently. When I use it alone it returns absolute part, but in constructions like `process.cwd()+'/somepath/somefile'` it kind of returning ''